# How pass parameter of map inside class validator schema

Tags: node.js, class-validator

I'm trying to pass each parameter of map function into validate function but the variable inside the validate function gives the last value of the map function

```
result = jsonData.map(async (id, index) => {
        customerInfo = getInfos(id, index);

        console.log("map " + customerInfo.id);

        return validate("customerSchema", id).then(errors => {

        console.log("validate " + customerInfo.id);

          if (errors.length > 0) {
            throw new HttpException(
              {
                status: HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,
                error: errors[0].constraints
              },
              403
            );
          }

        });
      });
```

expected output:

```
map 1
validate 1
map 2
validate 2
```

actual output:

```
map 1
map 2
validate 2
validate 2
```

why the validate get the second id twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *async* function then use *await* instead of *then*. You would get the expected output on using *await* as the control would wait for the execution of *validate* method but with *then* the control simply execute the stuff inside *then* on a different thread and continue to execute the *map* function on the main thread.